# LibGDX - Music problems

Tags: java, android, libgdx

WHAT I KNOW...

In LibGDX there are 2 classes for playing music/sounds. Music.java and Sound.java.

When you want to play a short sound(less than 1m), it is a good practice to use Sound.java class, because it loads to the memory. 
When you want to play long music (more than 1m), it is a good practice to use Music.java class, because it doesn't load in memory, but use streaming to play it.

WHAT I DO...

I use Music.java class in order to play background and loading music in my game.

WHAT PROBLEM I HAVE...

The problem is when I play music using Music.java class and when I read from disk some data (atlasses, for example), the music plays with jitter. So, as I understand, that the problem is in streaming, as I have that problem when I read from disk only. It seems, there is no way to open 2 fully separate threads for streaming. I mean, one for music and another for all other things such us read from a file or write. I tried to play the music in the new thread, but nothing changed.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You trying to use the Music class in a new Thread will not change anything. It will already be streaming in its own separately  managed Thread. I suspect you might have real hardware limitations, ie. you do not have enough real clocks to support the number of Threads you are running to achieve real concurrency... but just a guess I am afraid.

Comment: Hi @Laurence. Thanks. Hmm... I that case there is such a problem for all games written in libGDX? ((

Comment: It would be a problem for anyone trying to do multiple things at the same time with limited resources. What are your machine specs?

Comment: iPhone X, for example. Generally, mobile platforms.

Comment: Okay. Then this is strange... are you trying to do other things with threads? There should never really be a reason to, but if you are, then you need to be careful with how you pass data to and from the game loop.

Comment: I have no problem with other things. The problem is only with music streaming and only when I read a bunch of data from the disk. For example, read atlases.

Comment: Hmm, I take it you run this on other machines? Desktop? Do you see the same issue on all platforms?

Comment: Not the same result on desktop, but there is a little jetting on desktop too.

Comment: Okay so it does seem that at some point the loading of data is thrashing on the same thread on the iPhone...
Unless you want to dig into the weeds of it, I would recommend doing the loading of your assets in a carefully planned way, in silence. Sorry I haven't been of help.

Comment: Or switch to some fully loaded sound and loop that while you load large assets?

Comment: The problem is that I read from the disk during the game too.
For example, if the user buys a new creature from the shop, it's resources downloads from our backend and the loads from disk to the ram. So, I can't play a sound during that process, because there is background music, that is already playing. )

Comment: Hmmm, ya. Not sure what profiling tools you have access to for that particular hardware, but something must be thrashing... a candidate is the disk and driver driver. Choices are the same. Dig into the weed of how you are fetching and writing to disc. And the reading it. It is going to be some low level bottleneck on that device